# Using .GroupBy to remove list duplicates and also keep value from first list

Tags: c#, linq

Using .GroupBy() I was able to combine this list,

```
AppleId    Color
----------------
1          Green
1          Red
2          Red
3          Green
4          Red
4          Green
```

into this list:

```
AppleId    Green   Red
------------------------
1           1       1
2           0       1
3           1       0
4           1       1
```

The duplicate AppleId records have been removed and the Color column has been split into two Boolean columns.

However, what if I had another value I wanted to keep from the first list? So the first table would now be like this:

```
AppleId    Color     Value
-----------------------------
1          Green       Value1
1          Red         Value1
2          Red         Value2
3          Green       Value3
4          Red         Value4
4          Green       Value4
```

and the grouped table would be like this:

```
AppleId    Green   Red     Value
-----------------------------------
1           1       1       Value1
2           0       1       Value2
3           1       0       Value3
4           1       1       Value4
```

Here is the c# list:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item {Color = "Green", Id = 1, Value = Value1},
    new Item {Color = "Red", Id = 1, Value = Value1},
    new Item {Color = "Red", Id = 2, Value = Value2},
    new Item {Color = "Green", Id = 3, Value = Value3},
    new Item {Color = "Red", Id = 4, Value = Value4},
    new Item {Color = "Green", Id = 4, Value = Value4}
};
```

I tried using this

```
var q = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
             .Select(group => new 
                     {
                         Id = group.Key, 
                         Green = group.Any(item => item.Color == "Green"), 
                         Red = group.Any(item => item.Color == "Red"),
                         Value = x.Value
                     });
```

and some other variations, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
The idea is to group by using id and value

```
var q = items
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Value})
    .Select(group => new 
             {
                 Id = group.Key.Id, 
                 Green = group.Any(item => item.Color == "Green"), 
                 Red = group.Any(item => item.Color == "Red"),
                 Value = group.Key.Value,
             });
```

Comment: `Value` wouldn't need to be included in the `Select` statement?

Comment: Navig8tr and Mohammed
I think value should be included in the select. I have modified above..

Comment: Yes you're right masum7. Everything included in the `.GroupBy` statement is included in the `.Key` value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Color` is a function of `Id` just group on `Color` too. It won't change the number and contents of the groups.

```
...
group x by new { id, color } into g
...
```

You can now use `color` because it is part of the key: `g.Key.color`.

Comment: Could you provide a more complete answer?

Comment: How would it be written using `.GroupBy(x=>x.Id)`?

Comment: x => new { x.id, y.color }